# ctype_digit to only allow 10 digits starting with a 4

Tags: php

I am using the following function to only allow digits.

```
if (empty($VAT) || (!(ctype_digit($VAT)))) {
    $mistakes[] = 'ERROR - Your title is either empty or should only contain NUMBERS starting with a 4.';
```

Is there a way that i can add/modify this function to only accept 10 digits and it must start with the number 4?

Comment: Use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match)

Comment: No but you can write a new function to do that using regular expressions or string matching. all ctype_* functions do is check the character types not their actual values. I would however say that title is not a good name for something that should contain a 10 digit vat number

Comment: Oeps, forgot to change the error message.  title should be VAT Number.

Comment: @Anigel ctype_ functions *do not check type*, it checks the values. Please check from manual before claiming otherwise. The [manual entry](http://fi1.php.net/ctype_digit) clearly states it checks for numeric values in a text string, not parameter type - only allowed type is text.

Comment: @eis Perhaps you misunderstood me, I did not say it took a different variable type. it checks what types of characters are in the string it is given not if the specific values of those chars are > 40000 or some other arbitrary figure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use regular expressions for this:

```
if(preg_match('/^4\d{9}$/', $VAT) == 0){
   $mistakes[] = 'ERROR - Your title is either empty or should only contain NUMBERS starting with a 4.';
}
```

and If you ever need to match any other string or number pattern, this is a site you can test your regular expression on: [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/) it's got pointers and tutorials and everything to help you learn how to match string patterns and test your own regular expressions

Comment: Thank you very much for all the advice.  I used the preg_match.

Comment: no problem Alwina, check my edit

Answer (score 1):

[`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match) is what you looking for:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$number1 = '4123456789';
$number2 = '3123456789';

$regex = '/^4\d{9}$/';
// ^ test pattern: 4 in begining, at least 9 digits following.

echo $number1, ': ', preg_match($regex, $number1), PHP_EOL;
echo $number2, ': ', preg_match($regex, $number2), PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Output:

```
4123456789: 1
3123456789: 0
```

Updated source:

```
if (!preg_match('/^4\d{9}$/', $VAT)) {
    $mistakes[] = 'ERROR - Your title is either empty or should only contain NUMBERS starting with a 4.';
}
```

For variable number of digits use following regex: `'/^4\d{1,9}$/'`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `preg_match` and return matches or boolean

```
preg_match('/^[4]{1}[0-9]{9}$/', $VAT, $matches);
```

And alternative using:

```
$VAT = "4850999999";

if (preg_match('/^[4]{1}[0-9]{9}$/', $VAT))
    echo "Valid";
else
    echo "Invalid";
```

#### Means

`^[4]` Start with number 4 (four)

`{1}`  Initial number limit

`[0-9]` Allowed chars

`{9}` Required 9 units digit after first number

Answer (score 0):

Maybe isn't the best way, but using REGEX you can do it.

This is one way

```
preg_match('/4[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/', $string, $matches);
```

Where $string is the string that you want to check, and $matches, is where the concordant results gonna be saved.